find vertex with highest value of named attribute
Here's a node setup that I thought would find the vertex with the highest value of a named attribute, namely the noiz attribute produced by a noise texture.
Each vertex is sampled by index, and if its value is higher than the previous value then that value is stored, and the index of the vertex is stored. Except it doesn't. Can anyone explain to me why?
In the spreadsheet you can see that each vert has a noiz attribute, but the calculation from the repeat zone always produces whatever value is on the last vertex.

I tried another approach, storing a boolean value if the noiz value was higher than the last, but again no dice.


FWIW, using the Attribute Statistic node's Max output is probably easiest.

I'm actually less interested in the value, I want the index of the vertex with that value.

Once you have the max you can check which indices have that value.

Got it, thanks to @scurest for putting me on the right track. This works, with no repeat zone:

